# class std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::ListAllocator<std::pair<int, int> has no member named 'front'

Tags: c++, list, c++20

I'm trying to upgrade my code from C++11 standard to C++20, using gcc-12, on a Kubuntu20 OS.
I have a custom allocator:

```
namespace allocators {
template <class T,int n = 16384>
class ListAllocator : public std::allocator<T> {
public:
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
public:
    ListAllocator() : allocator<T>()                             {}
    ListAllocator(const ListAllocator<T,n>& a) : std::allocator<T>(a) {}
    ListAllocator(const allocator<T>& a) : std::allocator<T>(a)       {}

    char* _Charalloc(size_type N) {
        if (idx==0)
           return allocator<T>::_Charalloc(N);
        else
            return reinterpret_cast<char*>(arena[--idx]);
    }

    void deallocate(void* p, size_type s) {
        if (idx == n)
            allocator<T>::deallocate(p,s);
        else
            arena[idx++] = p;
    }


    static void deallocate() {
        while(idx) 
            ((allocator<T>*)0)->deallocate( reinterpret_cast<typename std::allocator<T>::pointer>(arena[--idx]) , size_type(sizeof(T)) );
    }

    static void*    arena[n];
    static size_t   idx;          // index of 1st emty field in arena
};


template <class T,int n>  void*  ListAllocator<T,n>::arena[n];
template <class T,int n>  size_t ListAllocator<T,n>::idx;

}
```

And I have a struct, containing the following:

```
 typedef T                           Coord;

  typedef std::pair<Coord , Coord >   Point;
  typedef ListAllocator<Point> ListPointAllocator;

  typedef std::list<Point2d,ListPointAllocator >   Pl;
  Pl*  plPtr;
  Point & edgeRef() { return beg ? plPtr->front() : plPtr->back();}
```

I get the error:
`class std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::ListAllocator<std::pair<int, int>, 16384> >'} has no member named 'front' class std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::ListAllocator<std::pair<int, int>, 16384> >'} has no member named 'back'`

I tried to find an explanation, but nothing came up. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is that the *full* and *complete* build log from your example code? There's no other output or informational notes?

Answer (score 0):

Your allocator does not fulfill the [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) requirements.

Without doing so using it as an allocator for a standard library template has undefined behavior and compilation failure is one of the luckier outcomes.

Some problems:

1. Your allocator is instantiated from a template that has non-type template parameters. Therefore no default `rebind<U>` member template is provided and you need to provide it yourself. Note that `std::allocator` doesn't provide `rebind` anymore since C++20. Before C++20 your allocator did inherit `rebind` from it, but it would rebind to `std::allocator<U>` which is wrong, technically UB, and would probably result in your custom allocation functions not actually being used.
   Don't inherit from `std::allocator`, it is unnecessary. Most functionality required for an *Allocator* are defaulted through `std::allocator_traits` anyway. So a minimal *Allocator* only needs to provide constructors, `value_type`, `allocate`, `deallocate` and `operator==` (before C++20 also `operator!=`). In your case `rebind` is also required as I explained above.
2. `_Charalloc` is a globally reserved identifier because it starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. You may not use it. An allocator should define a `allocate` member function instead, analogous to [`std::allocator::allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate).
3. `allocator<T>::_Charalloc` is an implementation detail of the standard library. You are not supposed to use it. If you want to refer to the underlying allocator's allocation, use `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::allocate` or just directly `::operator new` instead.
4. Your allocator does not check that the sizes of individual allocations are the same. There is no guarantee that `allocate` won't be called with varying sizes as argument. Also, after rebinding, different alignments for different types may be expected. So you can't reuse an old allocation without checking alignment requirements either.
5. You need a constructor of the form `template<typename U> ListAllocator(const ListAllocator<U,n>&);`.